# Why are InputAttributes and LabelAttributes of a CheckBox not rendered after a postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, postback

I’m seeing some weird behavior in the standard ASP.NET CheckBox control. Here’s a repro:

**ASPX markup**

```html
<form runat="server">
    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cb" Text="Foo" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit" />
</form>
```

**C# code-behind**

```cs
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        cb.Attributes.Add("data-a", "1");
        cb.InputAttributes.Add("data-b", "2");
        cb.LabelAttributes.Add("data-c", "3");
    }
}
```

On the initial page request, the CheckBox control renders all three `data` attributes:

```html
<span data-a="1">                                           <!-- RIGHT -->
    <input id="cb" type="checkbox" name="cb" data-b="2" />  <!-- RIGHT -->
    <label for="cb" data-c="3">Foo</label>                  <!-- RIGHT -->
</span>
```

But after I click the Submit button, the CheckBox control renders only the `data-a` attribute:

```html
<span data-a="1">                                           <!-- RIGHT -->
    <input id="cb" type="checkbox" name="cb" />             <!-- WRONG -->
    <label for="cb">Foo</label>                             <!-- WRONG -->
</span>
```

Why are the InputAttributes and LabelAttributes missing after a postback?

**Heisenbug Alert:** If I set a breakpoint in OnLoad, click the button, and then inspect the values of `cb.Attributes["data-a"]`, `cb.InputAttributes["data-b"]`, and `cb.LabelAttributes["data-c"]`, then the values are `1`, `2`, and `null` (instead of `3`) respectively. Also, inspecting the values affects the output!

```html
<span data-a="1">                                           <!-- RIGHT -->
    <input id="cb" type="checkbox" name="cb" data-b="2" />  <!-- RIGHT -->
    <label for="cb" data-b="2">Foo</label>                  <!-- WTF?! -->
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you were still stuck on this, it's a bug.

Upgrade to .net framework 4.8 (and greater) for a fix.

I see you also submitted the bug report to Microsoft: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/287564/buggy-handling-of-inputattributes-and-labelattribu.html

Comment: I'd intended to post an answer with a few details, but I never got around to doing it. Now you beat me to it. :-)

Comment: Thanks for raising it over on the developercommunity! It's clear that you put a lot of effort into the bug report and this question